# Subclass QList for Quicksort

Tags: qt, quicksort, qlist

Calling Qsort from QList does not appear to work for sorting on 2 columns. If this is the case I would like to subclass QList and add a Quicksort method that calls a “compare” function to determine the sort order.

Being new to Qt (mainly Delphi) I am having trouble implementing the code.
I hope the following expresses the “concept” of the code required:

```
//prototype
#define TComp = int compare(pointer1, pointer2);

int MyComp(p1, p2)
{
  if      (p1.x < p2.x) return –1
  else if (p1.x > p2.x) return  1
  else if (p1.y < p2.y) return –1
  else if (p1.y > p2.y) return  1
  else                  return  0
}

class TObjList : public QList
{
public:
  void mySort(MyComp);
private:
  void QuickSort(TComp MyComp);
};
```

This is a big ask, but I need the help at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things here I wouldn’t do:

1. Subclassing a container type like QList doesn’t make sense, as it has no virtual methods to reimplement. Just to add a helper function doesn’t justify subclassing, make it a free function.
2. Implement sorting as member function instead of a generic function like std::sort.
3. reimplement the whole sort algorithm just to get your own comparison operator used

I’d suggest to use std::sort and a custom comparison function (in C++11, this could use a lambda or std::tuple which implements lexicographical comparison like done here):

```
template <typename T>
bool xyLessThan(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{
    if (lhs.x == rhs.x)
        return lhs.y < rhs.y;
    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
```

And then e.g.

```
QList<Point> points;
...
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), &xyLessThan);
```

That uses a generic sorting algorithm which let's you specify the function to be used for comparison, which is `xyLessThan` here.

If you control the class of the elements (the T in QList) and if there’s a “natural” sorting, you can add an `operator<` like this:

```
bool Point::operator<(const Point &other) const
{
    if (x == other.x)
        return y < other.y;
    return x < other.x;
}
```

then you can just do

```
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end());
```

Comment: Thanks for an interesting and involved answer. It will take me some time to consume the content and bet back to you. Thanks again.